# update a json in node

Tags: node.js, json, express

```
{
  aps: []
}
```

I read it like this:

```
let apartments = require("path to json file);
apartments.aps.push(apa); // apa is a valid object
fs.writeFile("path", JSON.stringify(apartments));
```

aps will contain objs like this

```
{ "id":0, "address": "something"}
```

when I push in my json file I see

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: In node you can simply `const data = require('./yourJsonFile')` and nodejs will parse it object for you as long as `yourJsonFile` is a valid `json`

Comment: ok now it works, i can push to aps but what about to save the file?

Comment: `what about to save the file?` manually `fs.writeFile` after stringify

Comment: now my file contain [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `apas` is a string.  JSON is a text format for representing JavaScript Objects (hence the name); you'll need to parse it (using a suitable library) before you can use it as an object.

Comment: when I do JSON.parse(data); on console I see an error: parse is not a function

Comment: I did const JSON = require("nodemon/lib/utils");

Comment: JSON is natively available in nodejs. you don't need to require anything.

Comment: if i don't require it, I have an unrisolved variable problem

Comment: I have 8.10 version

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple working example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = require('./message.json');
// add new value
data.new = 'new value';
fs.writeFile('message.json', JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Original content:

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

Modified content:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"new":"new value"}
```